# php shell_exec character allowed and limit - JSON encoded string as parameter

Tags: php, json, command-line-interface, shell-exec

I'm trying to pass a JSON encoded string in php `shell_exec` function but it seems like it doesn't accept whole string.

My code:

```
$exec_string = json_encode( $data );
$command     = "php index.php exec_function " . $exec_string;
$output      = shell_exec( $command );`

echo "<pre>$output</pre>;
```

My index.php

```
public function exec_function ( $data ) {
  echo $data;
}
```

The function only echoes some part of the string like ~300 characters. The output string ends at the '\' character and the rest of the string starts with '/' character.

For this reason I can not further decode the JSON string.

Someone please help me out.

Thanks

UPDATE:

I just removed the variables with the '/\' characters and now it returns full string. And the returned string is without the double-quotes '"' so there's no way I can decode it. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the line with `$command` to the following:
`$command     = 'php index.php exec_function "' . $exec_string.'"';`
the problem is that you have some character that in the shell it thinks breaks the parameter so you have to enclose it with qoutes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any idea why it's not returning full JSON encoded string but without all double quotes? It's impossible for me to decode it. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know what you sent to the exec, maybe if I see that. However it seems it should output exactly what you give it.

Comment: I encoded the `$_POST` array. JSON encoded string always has double-quoted keys and its values. But when I pass it as `shell_exec` argument it receives without all double quotes. Ex. `{ "key": "value" }` becomes `{ key: value }`. Thanks.

Comment: it sounds like a printing issue only.